# how can I uninstall last firefox update

Tags: uninstallation

I was happy with the last version of Firefox and wish I never allowed auto updates because I am unhappy with the new browser and want to go back to it.  So how can I return the last version of Firefox and not have to use the new one?

Comment: Backup your profile, uninstall, and install an older version. [Install older version of FireFox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-older-version-of-firefox)

Comment: For future reference - questions relating to general computing belong on [Super User](https://superuser.com/). Stack Overflow is only for questions about programming.

Answer (score 0):

After a day of searching for browser add-on's to replace those I lost in the Firefox 57.0 update it became clear that my only option was to re-install version 56.0.2.  The newest version was a bit quicker and have several features that would be useful to some I found the older vision and the Legacy add-on's was the one I would stay with for now. This link will set you back to the 56.0.2 version.